# Corona SDK: how to bring one display object to front of another display object

Tags: actionscript-3, coronasdk, displayobject

I'm making a transition from AS3 to Corona. In AS3, one can add a movie clip using functions like addChild(),addChildAt(),getChildIndex(),setChildIndex() 
I wonder what is the equivalent of addChildAt() and setChildIndex() in Corona SDK

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean but there is the function 

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/toFront.html 

and

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/toBack.html
maybe it's that?

Comment: I realized that Corona does not implement that functionality, at least not yet.

Comment: Corona is powerful but limited, I hope you'll find another way to fix that! ;)